# Python/Django complicated/nested query

Tags: python, django

I'm a beginner with python and Django working on my first project. Step by step I managed to overcome almost all difficulties that I came across, but one problem caused that I got stuck and I have no more ideas how to solve it.
The goal is to display child(children) of each user that is currently at a particular playground. It should go like this: I have a "current visit" of a particular user and I want to display his/her child/children. I don't want to choose which child is at a playground with his/her parent, at this stage I assume that whole possible set of children goes with his/her parent:)

Here are my models:

```
    class Quarter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=QUARTER, default='not defined')

class Pground(models.Model):
    place = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    description = models.TextField()
    quarter = models.ForeignKey(Quarter)

class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    age = models.IntegerField(choices=AGE, default=-1)
    sex = models.IntegerField(choices=SEX, default=1)
    whose_child = models.ForeignKey(User)


class Parent(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    quarter = models.ForeignKey(Quarter)
    children = models.ManyToManyField(Child)   


class Visit(models.Model):
    who = models.ForeignKey(User)
    pground = models.ForeignKey(Pground)
    time_from = models.DateTimeField()
    time_to = models.DateTimeField()
```

And relevant view goes till now like this:

```
        class HomeLogView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = '/login/'
    def get(self, request):
        user = request.user
        quarter = user.parent.quarter
        pgrounds = quarter.pground_set.all()
        current_visits = {}
        for pground in pgrounds:
            now = datetime.now()
            current_visits[pground] = pground.visit_set.filter(time_from__lte=now, time_to__gte=now)
            current_visits[pground] = {}
            this_visits = pground.visit_set.filter(time_from__lte=now, time_to__gte=now)
            for visit in this_visits:
                current_visits[pground][visit] = Child.objects.filter(whose_child=visit.who)
                this_children = Child.objects.filter(whose_child=visit.who)

        ctx = {'user': user, 'quarter': quarter, 'pgrounds': pgrounds, 'current_visits': current_visits, 'this_visits': this_visits, 'this_children': this_children}
        return TemplateResponse(request, 'home_login.html', ctx)
```

So with a template (part):

```
<dt>{% for pground, current_visits in current_visits.items %}
            <dd><h3>{{pground.place}}</h3></dd>
                {% for visit in current_visits %}
            <dd>Użytkownik: <mark>{{visit.who}}</mark> na placyku od: {{visit.time_from}}
                do: {{visit.time_to}} {{visit.pground}} <a href="/new_message/{{visit.who.id}}">Send message</a></dd>
                {% for visit, this_visits in current_visits.items %}
                    {% for child in this_visits %}
                        {{child.name}} {{child.age}}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}                   
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        </dt>
```

I got whole set of children present at a particular playground attached to each visit. But my goal is to display information with this pattern: for each "current visit", on a basis of a parent, his/her child/children.

I would be really grateful for a piece of advice how to move from the place I got stuck. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: with current model design you are assuming that all the children of a particular parent are/is in the playground. If Not then your current model structure is incapable of handling this.

Comment: Make child also a User to capture the visit of the child not the parent.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. You're right, eventually there should be the option to choose which child/children are at the playground with its/their parent. But on this stage I'm not going to do this, I just want to display a child/full set of children of a particular user, which has a "current visit".

Answer (score 0):

Set related_name in Parent and Child models like

```
class Child(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
     age = models.IntegerField(choices=AGE, default=-1)
     sex = models.IntegerField(choices=SEX, default=1)
     whose_child = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='children')
```

While you are querying you can modify you query like:

```
this_visits = pground.visit_set.filter(time_from__lte=now, time_to__gte=now).prefetch_related('parent__children')
```

Assuming parent and children are you related names.